# Getdate() sql server no me devuelve valores en una busqueda

Tags: sql-server, date

tengo un store procedure donde inserto un correo y la fecha para una promoción.

```
> insert into ListadoPromociones (Correo, fecha) values ( @correo, GETDATE())
```

Como verán este store procedure inserta en una tabla el correo que completa el usuario y la fecha del día.

```
> idPromo       Correo                fecha 
> 10        micorreo@gmail.com      2023-02-12
```

Pero antes de insertarlo, con otro store procedure busco que el correo y la fecha no existan, porque cada correo solo puede solicitar una vez por día la promoción.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from ListadoPromociones where Correo=@correo and fecha = GETDATE()
```

El problema que tengo es que cuando ejecuto ese store procedure le paso como parametro micorreo@gmail.com, y lo ejecuto el 12 de febrero de 2023  siempre me devuelve 0, cuando hay un correo y una fecha del mismo día como ven.
Lo puedo solucionar con otra variable para la fecha y el formato mm dd yyyy, pero mi pregunta es por que no reconoce el getdate() la fecha del día en la tabla, no se si me explico. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es porque `GETDATE` retorna la fecha junto con la hora entonces la condición de búsqueda, al evaluarla,  se ve así:

```
where correo=@correo and '2023-02-12' = '2023-02-12 02:10:09.030'
```

Como bien dices la solución sería usar solo la parte de la fecha de `GETDATE`:

```
where correo=@correo and fecha = convert(varchar(10),getdate(), 126)
```

Comment: Cambia la conversión por `CONVERT( char(8), GETDATE(), 112)` para regresar un formato que no dependa de la configuración de la conexión.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo porque tienes que llamar a otro procedure, para hacer eso cuando la propia instrucción de `insert` te lo permite.

```
Create table ListadoPromociones (correo varchar(30), fecha datetime);
Insert into ListadoPromociones(correo, fecha)
Values
('correo1@cuenta.es','20230213');
```

Ahora con la misma instrucción puedes usar [exists](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/06/17/exists-como-se-implementa/) y obtener la inserción caso de que no se devuelvan filas.

```
insert into ListadoPromociones (Correo, fecha) 
Select @correo, GETDATE()
Where not exists (
    Select * from ListadoPromociones l
    where l.correo = @correo
    And l.fecha =Convert(date,getdate())
);
```

**El problema real es**: [GetDate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) devuelve `datetime` sin desplazamiento. Y estas comparando una fecha con una fecha/hora y no son idénticos. ***Importante***, para comparar con un campo que es de tipo `date`, debes de convertir el resultado de la función `getdate` al mismo tipo del campo. No uses conversiones a otros tipos, porque entonces, implicitamente, obligas al motor a convertir también el campo al tipo de comparación.

```
Declare @correo varchar(30)='correo1@cuenta.es'

insert into ListadoPromociones (Correo, fecha) 
Select @correo, GETDATE()
Where not exists (
    Select * from ListadoPromociones l
    where l.correo = @correo
    And l.fecha =Convert(date,getdate())
);
```

[image: Resultado]

Si pongo otro correo.

```
Declare @correo varchar(30)='correo2@cuenta.es'

insert into ListadoPromociones (Correo, fecha) 
Select @correo, GETDATE()
Where not exists (
    Select * from ListadoPromociones l
    where l.correo = @correo
    And l.fecha =Convert(date,getdate())
);
```

[image: Res3]